# Connect to database dynamically depending database table

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring

I'm trying to connect a database depending of a table who make a query. For example, I have **tableA**, **tableB** and **tableC**.

For tables **tableA** and **tableB** I want connect to database "**local**", and for **tableC** connects to database "**remote**".

I could change this in a configuration table of database and tell to **tableB** connects to "**remote**" database instead of "**local**" database.

I have followed this [example](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/), but I have not idea if is possible to know the table, or query, in the class ***CustomerRoutingDataSource***. Or perhaps there is another solution unknowed for me.

Thanks.

Comment: More importantly: what problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I have a distributed application. Depending of the server, some tables must be acceded locally and others remotely

I know that I could create 2 datasources, but I would like that the connection could be dynamic

Comment: Tables do not make queries. Queries are made to tables.

Comment: You can handle it with the same datasource. But in your query you can switch the tables.

Comment: If you use JPA in your project you could create *EntityManager* programatically like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988247/jpa-create-entitymanagerfactory-from-properties) post.

Comment: Thanks @DominikG, I will try it